# What is "localhost" server in Azure redirect URL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an App registered in Azure AD, and in the redirectUrl I want to use localhost, when I use localhost which server it will look for?

Comment: Localhost specifies your local application URL.For Ex: If you are running your app in http://localhost:8080 , then localhost will pick the application running in port 8080.

Comment: When I substitute proper IP in the FQDN https://test.point.com/azureSignInLoginAction.action in redirecturl this is able to resolve without any issue. when I use above mentioned in Redirect URL, my redirecturl is not receiving  authorization code. This is the error message I'm seeing when I try to open the redirectUrl with FQDN "Cannot sign in AZURE SSO user. Could not receive authorization code."

Comment: As mentioned, you need to add `https://` before the url

Answer (score 0):

As per this [Document](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/localhost/) it says,

> *localhost* is a **domain** reserved for **documentation and testing purposes**.
> If you access "http://localhost" in the browser, the request will remain in your own system.
>
> - Localhost refers to the machine/device where we are running our Application
> - Instead of localhost we can access with IP address `127.0.0.1`

- Thanks @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT for the comment, If we give RedirectURI as `http://localhost:portnumber` the request will be sent to the same device where we are accessing the app

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#localhost-exceptions) there are some exceptions for localhost redirect URIs

> http and https URI's are acceptable for localhost

***Taken References from:***

https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/localhost/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#localhost-exceptions